# Can you put SNES roms on a Super Mario Bros Game & Watch?

Tags: snes, super-mario-bros, nintendo-game-and-watch, super-mario-all-stars

I want to try to put Super Mario All-Stars Super Mario Bros 1 & 2(JPN) on the Game and Watch. I've seen some hacking videos on putting NES roms on it, but can you manipulate it to put SNES roms on it?

BONUS: Is there a way to change the clock so that it matches the All-Styles theme?

Comment: This would probably do better on Reddit's /r/ReverseEngineering or similar as it's very speculative. [The CPU](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M7) is 32-bit ARM, the firmware is moddable with custom hardware, and the display is full-color LCD. The nearest mention of the GPU though is that the screen displays 8-bit graphics, which is worthless to answer whether it handles anything more, but it is only about 35 millimeters/1.37795", so it's likely too small.

Answer (score 1):

This question was downvoted mostly because we do not help with modding, and that is very probably against the TOS of that collectible.

My personal guess? Well you can't usually use the exact same emulator for NES and SNES games. Its good to remember that the Super NES was not built as an extension or buildup to the original NES, but was the following console. So it's probably not the same architecture.

So by taking that into consideration, it is improbable that just because it can run NES game it can also run SNES games.

The [G&W collectible](https://www.nintendo.com/products/detail/game-and-watch-super-mario-bros/) was made to run NES and G&W games, so that's probably why  it can run other NES games (the NES/SNES classic had the same loophole, where its a basic emulator inside, so it could run any game from the same generation if you dumped the ROM on its memory). But it probably has just enough firepower to run NES, and wont be able to run things from a more advanced system like the SNES.